# How to select taxonomy term based on current language?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

My website has 3 languages. The *Tag* taxonomy is multilingual and for each term I added its translation. I created a block of a view using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module that selects one random term and displays it.

I need this block to show its content in the language currently set.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think the 1st (of 2) questions marked as duplicate should not be considered as duplicate, because of the "programatically" in the question (which is not what "this" question is about).

Comment: How do you know this question isn't asking for a programmatic solution @Pierre? Where does it say that?